# SSH key-only remote login, is disabling password a good practice?

Tags: ssh, security, password

I need a maintenance user which only requires a remote login. I'll preferably use only public keys to login into the account.

I thought of just creating the user with `useradd myuser`, adding later the required public keys to its `authorized_hosts` file.

`useradd` disables the password by default. Do I still require to run a `passwd -l myuser` to lock it?

Any drawbacks here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are some drawbacks here. You are using password-less authentication to increase security. Since giving password will be a second door to login to your system. So in

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

> ```
> PasswordAuthentication no
> RSAAuthentication yes
> PubkeyAuthentication yes
> AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
> ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
> GSSAPIAuthentication no
> ```

This changes will only authenticate with the public key, it will not ask password at any case. This will be a good security procedure to secure remote logins.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Ruban. I'm aware of the sshd `PasswordAuthentication no` config line, but it would apply globally, and I still require some users using password during remote login. Given this scenario, do you find any other issue?

Comment: If that is your case then what you have done is good @el.atomo. There would be no issues.